How to split the from one cell to two cell?
How to split from one cell to two cell?
Example:

A1: ABC: Apple Banana and Carrot
B1: ABC
C1: Apple Banana and Carrot

And how to include the arrayformula and leaveblank?
I tried this code:
=index(SPLIT(A1," ",true),1)

it shows only the ABC in the B1. It's also not working for the whole column and there's a word #VALUE! if it's blank.

You may try-
=IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A,": ",0)),"")

But, I would suggest you to use MAP() function like-
=MAP(A1:INDEX(A1:A,COUNTA(A1:A)),LAMBDA(x,SPLIT(x,": ",0)))



@FerdinandpalaspasII Glad to know. If it works then please consider accepting (tick mark) the answer to treat the thread as solved.
